# autofill form fields based on value from select field from database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysqli

How can I make other input field be auto filled and readonly from my database base on the value from select field or leave it empty if the value is unassigned?

```
<?php
//include auth.php file on all secure pages
require("../db.php");
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
header("Location: login");
exit(); }
?>
<?php require_once('header.php')?>

<div class="container content">
    <h2>Add Shipment</h2>



<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){

    txt=$("#ShipmentCustomerid").val();

      if(txt=='0')
       {
           fun1='';



    $("#ShipmentShipperphone").removeAttr('readonly');

    $("#ShipmentShipperaddress").removeAttr('readonly');

     $("#ShipmentShippername").removeAttr('readonly');


    $("#ShipmentShipperemail").removeAttr('readonly');

       }

       else
       {
          gum1='';             

       $("#ShipmentShipperphone").attr('readonly',true);

           $("#ShipmentShipperaddress").attr('readonly',true);

        $("#ShipmentShippername").attr('readonly',true);
       $.get("Shipperphone/"+txt,{ },function(result){
           result = $.trim(result)
      $("#ShipmentShipperphone").val(result);


    });

       $.get("Shipperaddress/"+txt,{ },function(result){
           result = $.trim(result)
      $("#ShipmentShipperaddress").val(result);


    });


        $.get("newshippername/"+txt,{ },function(result){
           result = $.trim(result)
      $("#ShipmentShippername").val(result);


    });



     $.get("shipperemail/"+txt,{ },function(result){
           result = $.trim(result)
      $("#ShipmentShipperemail").val(result);


    });



       }


  $("#ShipmentCustomerid").change(function(){

     txt=$("#ShipmentCustomerid").val();

       if(txt=='0')
       {
           fun='';

           $("#ShipmentShipperphone").removeAttr('readonly');

           $("#ShipmentShipperaddress").removeAttr('readonly');
           $("#ShipmentShippername").removeAttr('readonly');

           $("#ShipmentShipperphone").val(fun);

            $("#ShipmentShipperaddress").val(fun);

             $("#ShipmentShippername").val(fun);

             $("#ShipmentShipperemail").val(fun);

            $("#ShipmentShipperemail").removeAttr('readonly');

       }

       else
       {
          gum=''; 


       $("#ShipmentShipperphone").attr('readonly',true);

           $("#ShipmentShipperaddress").attr('readonly',true);

       $("#ShipmentShippername").attr('readonly',true);

       $("#ShipmentShipperemail").attr('readonly',true);

       $.get("Shipperphone/"+txt,{ },function(result){

      $("#ShipmentShipperphone").val(result);


    });

       $.get("Shipperaddress/"+txt,{ },function(result){

      $("#ShipmentShipperaddress").val(result);


    });

     $.get("Shipperphone/"+txt,{ },function(result){
           result = $.trim(result)
      $("#ShipmentShipperphone").val(result);


    });

  $.get("newshippername/"+txt,{ },function(result){
           result = $.trim(result)
      $("#ShipmentShippername").val(result);


    });
$.get("shipperemail/"+txt,{ },function(result){
           result = $.trim(result)
      $("#ShipmentShipperemail").val(result);


    });



       }


  });
});

</script>
<div id="test"></div>
<div class="col-md-4">


 <form action="add_shipment" id="ShipmentAddForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">  
    <div class="form-group">
    <h4>Shipper info :</h4>
    </div>

     <div class="form-group"><label for="ShipmentCustomerid">Choose</label><select name="id" class="form-control" id="ShipmentCustomerid">
<option value="0">Unassigned</option>
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Id,customername,phone,address,email FROM customer");
                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
            <option value="<?=$row[0]?>"><?=$row[1]?></option>
        <?php }
    ?>
</select></div>   

     <div class="form-group required"><label for="ShipmentShippername">Shippername</label><input name=""  class="form-control" maxlength="35" type="text" id="ShipmentShippername" required="required"/></div>  
           <div class="form-group"><label for="ShipmentShipperphone">Phone</label><input name="" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" maxlength="30" type="text" id="ShipmentShipperphone"/></div>       



 <div class="form-group required"><label for="ShipmentShipperaddress">Address</label><textarea name="" id="ShipmentShipperaddress" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" cols="30" rows="6" required="required"></textarea></div>    



  <div class="form-group"><label for="ShipmentShipperemail">Email</label><input name="]" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" maxlength="55" type="text" id="ShipmentShipperemail"/>

  </div>
```

Here is the code and will really more contribution on how to make it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ajax post or get for autocomplete.

reference : http://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-autocomplete-country-example/

```
 // AJAX call for autocomplete 
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search-box").keyup(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "readCountry.php",
    data:'keyword='+$(this).val(),
    beforeSend: function(){
        $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF url(LoaderIcon.gif) 
  no-repeat 165px");
    },
    success: function(data){
        $("#suggesstion-box").show();
        $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
        $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF");
       }
       });
    });
});
//To select country name
function selectCountry(val) {
$("#search-box").val(val);
$("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
```